# Question on open polymorphism (motivation - output data to diff file types)

Tags: python, polymorphism

Let's say I have some class, and within instances of that class I want to be able to output certain data to various file types e.g. CSV, SQL, PDF, etc.

The simplest way is just a series of if statements, but that is generally a closed system.  Anybody who wants to extend the code has to have control of the class and the ability to modify the existing code.

Here is a really contrived example just to give something a little more concrete:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self,species,eats):
        self.species = species
        self.eats    = eats
        self.data_outputs {'sql':(server,table), 'csv':path}    

    def is_carnivorous(self):
        self.eats == 'meat'

    def is_hippie(self):
        self.eats == 'wheatgrass'

    def write(self,output_type,data):
        output_loc = self.data_outputs[output_type]
        if output_type   == 'sql':
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(some_insert_statement,data)
        elif output_type  == 'csv':
            with open(path,"r") as out:
                out.write(data)
```

If the logic for `write` is very involved, maybe delegating to a class to handle the logic could make the method a little bit cleaner:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self,species,eats):
        self.species = species
        self.eats    = eats
        self.data_outputs {'sql':(server,table), 'csv':path}    

    def is_carnivorous(self):
        self.eats == 'meat'

    def is_hippie(self):
        self.eats == 'wheatgrass'

    def write(self,output_type,data):
            output_loc = self.data_outputs[output_type]
            if output_type   == 'sql':
                SQLWriter.write(*output_loc,self.data)
            elif output_type  == 'csv':
                CSVWriter.write(output_loc,data)


class SQLWriter:
    def write(self,server,table,data):
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(some_insert_statement,data)


class CSVWriter:
    def write(self,path,data):
        with open(path,"r") as out:
            out.write(data)
```

Either way, both systems are closed, since modifying the write behavior requires subclassing the entire `Animal` class just to override `write`.  It's arguably even worse in the class delegation example because now you've coupled class creation with the `write` method so now every time you want to make a new output type you have to both modify the `write_data` method ,*and* make the appropriate class.

Is the pythonic solution to something like this to just use `SQLWriter` and `CSVWriter` as mixins?:

```
class Animal(CSVWriter):
    def __init__(self,species,eats):
        self.species = species
        self.eats    = eats

    def is_carnivorous(self):
        self.eats == 'meat'

    def is_hippie(self):
        self.eats == 'wheatgrass'
```

This keeps the system open, in that anybody who wants to make a new output type simply needs to write a new mixin and inherit from it, and no existing code needs to be touched to do this.  However - the users of `Animal` 
need to be aware that they must inherit from a mixin to get the `write` capability, which doesn't seem ideal.

If the write method was dependent on the actual type of class containing the data (`Animal` in this example), this would be straightforward in that i'd just have a `write` method in that class which any subclassers can override.  But in this example I want the `write` method to be polymorphic on specific data within the class, not on the class itself.

What is the standard Pythonic (or more generally Object Oriented) solution to this?

---

**EDIT**: If you're going to downvote - at least explain what your problem with the question is so I can fix it accordingly.

Comment: I can't answer in terms of the "python way" or the tools that knowledgeable python practitioners work.  I can say that your second option is definitely more modular, and separates the concern of how to write from the concern of how to be an animal.  Let your CSVWriter or your SQLWriter handle the details that it needs to, and your Animal be ignorant of what writer you are using.  Just supply what you need, and as long as they have a common interface, you don't need to worry about the output type.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch appreciate the response  - by second version do you mean the mixin example (bottom-most), or the class delegation example?  There are actually three versions 1.)if statements with all logic embedded 2.) if statement with class delegation 3.) mixins

Comment: @BerinLoritsch Also - I definitely want the animal to be ignorant of how writing is performed, which is what I'm trying to accomplish, but at some level in each example that is not the case.  The final example is probably the closest, but then the user is forced to be aware of the need to use a mixin.

Comment: Have a look at [visitor pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor).  I've used visitors for collecting data and generating outputs in different formats.

Comment: "I want the write method to be polymorphic on specific data within the class, not on the class itself."  That just screams that you have a class hiding within your class. Pull the data and the method out into their own object and delegate to it.

Comment: @Solaxun - the write method itself could be an interface. class OutputWriter(object){} class Animal(self, species, eats, outputWriter){} 
csvAnimal = new Animal(species.dog, eats.food, new CSVWriter())

Comment: @candied_orange The thought did cross my mind, but I didn't feel like a separate class was justified for what would be a glorified data container, since all I wanted out of it is the `write` method.  For instance, in my goofy example above, maybe we are storing everything the animal has eaten along with it's reaction in a list or something.  It would seem that if all I wanted was the ability to write this list to different output formats, creating a class to wrap the list would be overkill.  Even then, the wrapped class would need to know how to write, so I think i might end up where I started

Comment: @AnthonyJClink Interesting thought - so you saying to create the relevant writer classes and then simply pass whichever one you want in during instance creation?  Seems similar to the mixin approach.

Comment: surely the obvious solution is to pass the writer in as parameter on the save method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both your examples, the `Animal` class is tightly coupled to the writers, since `Animal` directly uses `SQLWriter` and `CSVWriter`. If you want to add a new output format, you have to touch the `Animal` class. This may not seem so bad at first, but once you get more writable classes, adding new formats becomes a huge workload because all those classes need to be changed. In terms of complexity, adding a new format is O(n) where n is the number of writable classes.

A better solution is to pass the writer as argument to the write function. Then you can change the output format just by passing a different writer and the writable classes stay untouched. The following example should give you an idea:

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, species, eats):
        self.species = species
        self.eats = eats

    def store(self, writer):
        writer.write(self.species)
        writer.write(self.eats)


class SQLWriter(object):
    def __init__(self, server, table):
        self.server = server
        self.table = table

    def write(self, data):
        print("Storing", data, "in SQL", self.server, self.table)


class CSVWriter(object):
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    def write(self, data):
        print("Storing", data, "in CSV file", self.path)


def main():
    my_animal = Animal("some_species", "some_food")

    csv_writer = CSVWriter("some_file.csv")
    my_animal.store(csv_writer)

    sql_writer = SQLWriter("some_server", "some_table")
    my_animal.store(sql_writer)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This is the option I would go with.  It's essentially a simple form of the GoF Builder pattern (not to be confused with Builder as described by Josh Bloch.)  This approach starts to shine when you have multiple complex representations.  The class describes itself to the Builder and the Builder builds a representation based on that description.

Comment: This option definitely fits best - I was vastly over-complicating things. I did look into the visitor pattern recommend above, but it seemed heavy handed for what I wanted to do (don't need double dispatch, just single on the first argument).

Answer (score 0):

The system wont allow comment as a newby to the site!

This sounds a lot like method/function overloading.

I come from C++ background, which supports comprehensive function and method overloading. I know Python is also supposed to support it - but I can't be sure to what extent.

The idea is in your Animal class you can define as many versions of Writer() as you like, all with the same name "writer" but signatures different on the type and number of parameters.

Used in its simplest form, if you know your data is SQL then invoke Writer("SQL",connection etc) and if you know your data is CSV invoke Writer("CSV", filepath etc).

With a bit of thought this could be made automatic and the suggestion of Visitor pattern or more likely "double dispatch" would get you in the right direction.

Overloading of function names may be what you mean when you ask for "polymorphism on data".   (Or not if I misunderstood what you are asking :-) )